# R or Python:Non-linear Machine Learning with Variable Importance

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, feature-selection, random-forest

I am aware of the Random Forest implementation with variable importance in R and Python. Are there any others out there for classification? Can Lasso be used in a non-linear context?

Answer (score 1):

As others commented the lasso-type regularization can be used within NL contexts-I think the important is what are you referring to by nonlinear model? is that it is nonlinear in its predictors or inits estimation? for non linear parameters you can look at splines or GAM, GBM or xgboost( which they are both based on boosting framework, similar to random forest). the latter two give you variable importance... the first two give you the significant factors and their p-value.

Comment: This might be a semantic argument, but L1 penalties can absolutely be included in NL models.  It's a common approach with GLMs.

Comment: @RomRom it is non-linear in its predictors (I would like to capture the interactions between the predictors)

Comment: I think it is good if you try GBM and xgboost if your aim is attribute selection and their relative importance...I think Lasso can be used in nonlinear context too but refer to the package manual for details and whether that can be used... the only major difference here is that Lasso is very sensitive to missing data, so if you have missing data, perhaps better to  choose from boosting methods (GBM, or Xgboost)

Answer (score 1):

L1 regularization can be employed in nonlinear estimation and classification problems.  See for example the documentation in Python's scikit-learn package:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html

This section includes a number of generalized linear models (linear and nonlinear), several of which include L1 regularization as an option (with logistic regression being one such example of a nonlinear model with "sparse variable selection" properties when L1 regularization is used).

Note that L1 regularization is also frequently used in neural nets to moderate overfitting:

http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_mlp.html

Comment: Generalized linear models such as logistic regression are still linear in their parameters..When people say "logistic regression"  they normally refer to a binomial model with logit link - the model is linear in parameters and is in the exponential family, so is a GLM...so although i empathise why logistic regression is nonlinear (as in many texts), but it makes it so difficult to differentiate from generalized non-linear model if you already characterised GLMs as "nonlinear models"!

Comment: More general nonlinear solver techniques can and do make use of L1 regularization, so I think the answer stands.  It is not a requirement that the problem be GLM to be able to use L1 regularization.  Any convex likelihood maximization or error minimization optimization routine can leverage L1 regularization.